# ServiceActivationException for WCF service hosted on IIS 7

Tags: wcf, iis-7

We have RESTful WCF service hosted in IIS 7. We want service to be available for both http and https. So we have added 2 bindings for service host-
**http**://service.abc.com
**https**://service.abc.com

All services implementing **single contract** work well, but we get **System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException** for any service which implements **more than one** contracts.

Everything works fine with only one type of binding either **http** or **https**.

Any solution?

service configuration -

```
<services>
<service behaviorConfiguration="RESTServiceBehavior" name="App.Services.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="App.Contract.Services.IService1"                            bindingConfiguration="RESTServiceBinding"></endpoint>
</service>
</services>

<behaviors>
<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webBehavior">
        <webHttp/>
        <restGlobalErrorHandler/>
    </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>

<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RESTServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="App.Services.AuthorizationManager, App.Services" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>

<bindings>
<webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="RESTServiceBinding">
        <security mode="Transport">
        </security>
    </binding>
</webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: I still don't understand why people ask questions about errors they get without posting the message of the error. You should also provide more details about how you configure services.

Answer (score 0):

i am new to wcf but i have read it on stackoverflow that if your service have several contracts then you have to add reference for each contract. if there are 4 contracts then 4 service reference has to be created

Comment: No. You are still adding single reference but you will get 4 proxies.

Answer (score 0):

You need two endpoints for each contract you want to expose on the service. One endpoint will be for HTTP and second for HTTPS:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="RESTServiceBehavior" name="App.Services.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="RESTServiceBinding" contract="App.Contract.Services.IService1" />
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" 
              contract="App.Contract.Services.IService1" />
</service>
```